# Divisibility of $\operatorname{ord}\left(b\right)$ by specific power of $r$ for $b \in \mathbb{F}_q \setminus \{0\}$ where $r$ prime

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

I am currently studying toward understanding the Berlekamp–Zassenhaus algorithm for factorizing polynomials, using ['Algorithms of Informatics' (AnTonCom, Budapest, 2011)](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/FirstExpert/Vol1frame12December.pdf).
While studying some algebraic preliminaries in chapter 5, I stumbled upon the following lemma (see p. 235):

**Lemma 5.32** *Let be a prime. In a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ there exists an element which is not an $r$-th power if and only if $q \equiv 1 \pmod r$. If $b \in \mathbb{F}_q$ is such an element, then the polynomial $x^r - b$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$, and so $\mathbb{F}_q[x]/(x^r-b)$ is a field with $q^r$ elements.*

The proof of the implication

*$q \equiv 1\pmod r$ $\implies$ There is an element which is not an $r$-th power*

assumes $r \mid q - 1$, giving the $r$-th powers explicitly as
$$
0,\, 1,\, a^r,\, \left(a^r\right)^2, \dots ,\, 
\left(a^r\right)^{(q - 1)/r - 1}
$$
where $a$ is a generator of the cyclic group $\mathbb{F}_q\setminus \left\{0\right\}$ and then picks $s$ maximal such that $r^s \mid q-1$.

I understood all this, however I'm at a loss at how to prove the next statement the author makes:

> Then the order of an element $b \in \mathbb{F}_q\setminus\{0\}$ is divisible by $r^s$ if and only if $b$ is not an $r$-th power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the explicit listing given, one can read off that all nonzero
$r$-th powers constitute a cyclic group generated by $a^r$ of order
$(q-1)/r$.   By initial assumption, this implies $r^s \nmid 
\mathop{ord}(a^r) = (q - 1)/r\,$, by maximality of $s$. But then, $r^s
\nmid  \mathop{ord}\left(\left(a^r\right)^j\right)$ for all $j$, since
$$ \mathop{ord}\left(\left(a^r\right)^j\right) \mid
\mathop{ord}\left(\left(a^r\right)\right) $$ by LaGrange's theorem.
This shows that no nonzero $r$-th power is of order divisible by
$r^s$.

Now, assume that $b \neq 0$ is not an $r$-th power. This means that $b
= a^l$ with $r \nmid l$. Since $$ 1 = b^{\mathop{ord}\left(b\right)} = a ^ {l \cdot \mathop{ord}\left(b\right)} $$ we have $r^s \mid q - 1
\mid l \cdot \mathop{ord}\left(a\right)$, so that $r^s \mid l \cdot
\mathop{ord}\left(a\right)$ which proves $r^s \mid ord\left(b\right)$,
because $r$ is prime and $r \nmid l$ (use the
unique-prime-factorization-theorem).